# Why do html tags appear in my html R Markdown document

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

In R Studio I produce a table using Kable and Knit. However, the table does not render correctly and includes html tags. Is there a fix for this or some way around it?

[image: link here to a snippet of the table]

Comment: Any way you can post your dataset online?

Comment: Any way you can upload the html online?

Comment: Looks like you should double check the raw data for cap_3 capability and aud_format_m function...

Comment: Hi everyone, thanks for taking an interest. It's on a public repository: [link](https://github.com/antrogers/basicfinancedemo). Lines 209 to 217, seems like a <span> tag is going awry.

Comment: I've looked at this a bit more. Kable seems to create the table correctly which I can save as an image and looks fine. It seems to go awry using knit to produce the html doc.